# rpm build error

Tags: build, rpm

I tried to build a rpm package which is giving me the following error

- /usr/lib/rpm/find-debuginfo.sh /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/RPMS
  find: invalid predicate `'
  error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.86590 (%install)
  what could be the reason .can any one help me in this...Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try defining the `BuildRoot` variable in your spec file. The find-debuginfo script looks in to that directory several times, and will die without it.

This will usually look something like: `BuildRoot: %{_tmpdir}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}`

As to your second question, I can't say without seeing spec file and sources directly, and I am by no means an RPM expert. I will recommend you to Chapter 13 of Maximum RPM(there are copies available free online), and the notes from Tom Callaway's presentation on [How to make good RPM packages](http://spot.fedorapeople.org/Summit2008/) - I've found the spec examples here to be very helpful in the past.

Comment: Missing BuildRoot is the exact root of the problem - defining it (like it should have been to start with..) solves the problem fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In your spec you can do this at the top:

```
%define debug_package %{nil}
```

This should bypass this problem

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this same problem when attempting to build on a RedHat 5.3 server.  Here is what I found.  The error appears to be caused by an empty `RPM_BUILD_ROOT` variable.  Below is one offending line:

```
find "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT" ! -path "${debugdir}/*.debug" -type f \
                 \( -perm -0100 -or -perm -0010 -or -perm -0001 \) \
                 -print |
```

If `RPM_BUILD_ROOT` hasn't been defined, then the first argument to find is an empty string "", which causes this error.  Interestingly enough, if you remove the quotes from around `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`, then command works fine since the first argument would become the "!".  Since it's not required to define a "`BuildRoot`:" in the spec file, this certainly looks like a bug to me.